# OSError 54 - when loading data

Tags: python, download, pycharm, connection

When i load data, these errors show up:

....
File "/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/990-xml-database/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 318, in recv_into

raise SocketError(str(e))

OSError: (54, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

raise SocketError(str(e))

urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...

raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

Any idea what's wrong / how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl in the code